# How to create new string by indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Say I have a string 'Area51' and an array ['0051'], how would I go about replacing the 51 in the string with the array so that the output reads 'Area0051'. Assume that I have another function that finds my transform_array but it's not significant to this code.

```
string = 'Area51'
transformation_array = ['0051']
```

Ideally, this would extend to examples such as:

```
string = '22Area51'
transform_array = ['0022','0051']
# Outputting -> '0022Area0051'
```

I know strings are immutable so I have to create a new string and can't use replace.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
import re
string = '22Area51'
nums = re.findall("(\d+",string)
transform_array = ['0022','0051']

new_string = ''
for i in range(len(nums)):
    k = s.index(nums[i])
    new_string += string[s[:k] + transform_array[i]
```

But this would output:

```
First iteration:
>>> '0022Area51'
Second iteration
>>> '22Area0051'
```

I can't seem to wrap my mind on how to put it together. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems that you just need to prepend number sequence with `00`. what if some number is not reflected in `transform_array` ? What if `string = '22Area51'` and `transform_array = ['0051','0032']` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The 00 was just for example, for each number in nums there is a respective transform in the transform array at the same index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)) and `re.sub` with custom sub function:

```
string = '22Area51'
transform_array = ['0022','0051']

import re
from itertools import cycle

c = cycle(transform_array)
print(re.sub(r'\d+', lambda g: next(c), string))
```

Prints:

```
0022Area0051
```

Or, if number of digit groups matches the length of transform array:

```
import re
c = iter(transform_array)
print(re.sub(r'\d+', lambda g: next(c), string))
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. Would this have an O(n) run time (just my scan from the docs) since it just has the for loop over each element.

Comment: @Safder Yes, O(n). I updated my answer and added a version without `cycle()`

Answer (score 1):

With simple builtin `iter` feature:

```
import re

string = '22Area51'
transform_array = ['0022','0051']
tr_arr_iter = iter(transform_array)   # prepare iterator
res = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda n: next(tr_arr_iter), string)

print(res)    # 0022Area0051
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
string = '22Area51'
transform_array = ['0022', '0051']

new_string = string
nums = re.findall(r'\d+', string)
for num in nums:
    for el in transform_array:
        if num in el:
            new_string = new_string.replace(num, el)

print(new_string) #0022Area0051
```